# How to select two products where it is in same OrderDetails

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How do I select an order with two products in the `OrderDetails`?

For example, if I have 4 orders:

```
order id: 11000 contains: p1, p3, p5, p9
order id: 12000 contains: p1, p4, p5, p8
order id: 13000 contains: p2, p3, p5, p7
order id: 14000 contains: p1, p3, p5, p8
order id: 15000 contains: p2, p3, p6, p9
```

I want to select order ids where they contain p1 and p9

The expected result: 11000, 12000, 14000

How do I do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Why not return `15000` as well?  Are those values stored as comma delimited or separate columns?  If separate columns, use `in` or `or`.  If comma delimited, consider changing -- but if you can't, you can use `like` multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
SELECT id
FROM OrderDetails
WHERE Product IN ('p1','p9')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product) = 2
```

to get the `OrderDetails` PK value that satisfies the condition set.

**Edit:**

To get the count of the PK values, you can wrap the above query in a subquery and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT id
  FROM OrderDetails
  WHERE Product IN ('p1','p9')
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product) = 2) AS t
```

Comment: thanks Giorgos Betsos , Can Help me Again

If i want count this orders it contain this products

i want The Final result = 3 not 11000, 12000, 14000

Comment: @YasserBahnasy So, the expected result is 3?

Comment: eny number , i suggest number for my example :)

Comment: Excellent Very Thanks, possible help me again to get a percentage of the result also of the total number of bills?

And Thanks Again

Comment: @YasserBahnasy I think this is something completely different from the original post. Try posting a new question perhaps? Also, its a good practice to mark as accepted an answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry I did not know it, because I am a new user on the site
Thank you :)

Comment: possible help me again to get a percentage of the result also of the total number of bills? And Thanks Again