# Get a percentage of the result and of the total number of bills

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need the percentage of the value of the total number of sales with some producers in all applications The result is, for example, 12%.

This code calculates the number of orders:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT id
  FROM OrderDetails
  WHERE Product IN ('p1','p9')
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product) = 2) AS t
```

You can understand me if you read [How to select two products where it is in same OrderDetails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781468/how-to-select-two-products-where-it-is-in-same-orderdetails)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Can you add more details as to how you want your result as, it is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want the proportion of orders that have the two products.  You can do so as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalOrders,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NumProducts = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OrdersWithBothProducts,
       AVG(CASE WHEN NumProducts = 2 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as Proportion_OrdersWithBothProducts,
FROM (SELECT id,
             COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Product IN ('p1','p9') THEN Product END) as NumProducts
      FROM OrderDetails od
      GROUP BY id
     ) o;
```

Comment: I have need to the percentage of the value of the total number of sale with some producers in all applications
The result is, for example: 12%

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [Northwind]

SELECT
    CONVERT
    (VARCHAR,
        CONVERT
        (DECIMAL(3,2),
            CONVERT
            (DECIMAL(3, 2),
                (SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM (
                        SELECT [OrderID]
                            FROM  [Northwind].[dbo].[Order Details]
                            WHERE [ProductID] IN (41,51)
                            GROUP BY [OrderID]
                            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [ProductID]) = 2
                    ) AS T
                )
            )
            /
            (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders]
            )
            *
            100
        )
    )
    +
    '%'
```